# Activating a constraint which was uninstalled in the storyboard

Tags: ios, storyboard, interface-builder

I have a view which contains a few constraints. Some of them have the Installed checkbox turned off. I am trying to activate and deactivate specific constraints depending on the state of my application.

The problem is that when the installed checkbox is turned off I can't activate the constraints and also I can't deactivate the installed constraints. 
I need to mention that I use strong references for the constraints in my size classes properties. I also tried an approach to call `setNeedsUpdateConstraints` and updateConstraintsIfNeeded, `setNeedsLayout` and `layoutIfNeeded`, after activating/deactivating the constraints.

I couldn't find any documentation regarding this behavior so why is this happening?

Comment: May be you forgot to connect the constraints with IBOutlet variables? Or you have a different VC class in the storyboard? To exam this add breakpoint to viewDidLoad function and look at the IBOutlet variables.

Comment: You should connect an IBOutlet for constraints and update constraintVariable.active = Yes/No according to your requirement. Call layoutIfNeeded method after that.

Comment: I checked the IBOutlets and they are fine. When I call setActive it even changes the value of the active property, but when I Debug the View Hierarchy I can't find the uninstalled and activated constraints (through code). I only have the installed properties (which I've set them to be deactivated through code). I also called layoutIfNeeded and every posible combination of constraints/layout update.

Comment: I had the same problem and I could solve it by invalidating the constraints with `setNeedsUpdateConstraints()` then deactivating and activating the necessary constraints in `updateConstraints()`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Be sure that you put your code in the right place

```
override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
// write your code here 
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Take `OutLet` for that particular constraint for Example:

```
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet NSLayoutConstraint *constraint;)
//For Installing

[self.view addConstraint: constraint]

//For Uninstalling 

[self.view removeConstraint: constraint]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set the `.isActive` property at any time. Remember however to include it on the main thread by using `DispatchQueue.main.async { ... }`